# Various errors when accessing phpMyAdmin tables

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin version 5.0.1 on windows 10 as part of xampp's bundle.
I accessed phpMyAdmin where on the left field I click on a table then expand, as soon as I click on any sub table I get an annoying error. I really do not want to reinstall everything or it will take me forever  so I was wondering if this can be fixed?
The error list is huge listing everything but here is a section of the error if that helps?
Sorry but the nice format seems to be lost when reposting it here.

> Notice in .\libraries\classes\Core.php#1285 Undefined index:
> HMAC_secret
>
> Backtrace
>
> .\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#1720:
> PhpMyAdmin\Core::signSqlQuery(string 'SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY
> `members`.`memberID` DESC')
> .\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#1103:
> PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->_getOrderLinkAndSortedHeaderHtml( , array,
> array, integer 0, string 'SELECT * FROM `members` ', integer 250,
> string '', array, boolean false, NULL, )
> .\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#1220:
> PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->_getTableHeadersForColumns( array, array,
> array, array, array, boolean false, string 'SELECT * FROM `members` ',
> ) .\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#4292:
> PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->_getTableHeaders( array, array, string
> 'SELECT * FROM `members` ', array, array, array, boolean false, )
> .\libraries\classes\Sql.php#1666:
> PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->getTable( , array, array, boolean false, )
> .\libraries\classes\Sql.php#2002:
> PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable( , string
> './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, array, boolean true, integer 196,
> integer 196, NULL, , array, ) .\libraries\classes\Sql.php#2271:
> PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getQueryResponseForResultsReturned( , array, string
> 'members', string 'members', NULL, NULL, , string
> './themes/pmahomme/img/', integer 196, integer 196, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, NULL, string 'SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY `memberID` ASC ',
> NULL, ) .\libraries\classes\Sql.php#2100:
> PhpMyAdmin\Sql->executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean true,
> string 'members', string 'members', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, string
> 'sql.php?db=members&table=members&sql_query=SELECT+%2A+FROM+%60members%60+ORDER+BY+%60memberID%60+ASC+',
> string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'SELECT *
> FROM `members` ORDER BY `memberID` ASC ', NULL, NULL, ) .\sql.php#241:
> PhpMyAdmin\Sql->executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse( array, boolean true,
> string 'members', string 'members', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
> NULL, string
> 'sql.php?db=members&table=members&sql_query=SELECT+%2A+FROM+%60members%60+ORDER+BY+%60memberID%60+ASC+',
> string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'SELECT *
> FROM `members` ORDER BY `memberID` ASC ', NULL, NULL, )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is a known issue. The suggested workaround is to login and logout: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15401

Comment: For some reason I do not see a login or logout option on my phpMyAdmin but Just as I posted this I found a fast fix, by the homepage icon in phpMyAdmin there is another icon called Empty Session Data, I clicked it and it seems to have solved the problem. thanks I will copy that link for future reference.

Comment: Perfect. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer, so that other people with the same issue can easily solve it

Comment: I had to wait several minutes before I could mark it as solved. thanks again